# Why iPad Camera photos are not synced automatically to iCloud?

Tags: ipad, icloud, photos, data-synchronization

I have automatic sync on in my iPad. 
I have had my iPad in 3G/4G network and my home wifi. 
I access my iCloud in the internet browser at icloud.com but no pictures are visible there. 
In iCloud settings

- Photos On
- iCloud Photo Library On
- Optimise iPad Storage On
- Upload to my Photo Stream On
- ICloud Photo Sharing On

In Photos and Camera

- iCloud Photo Libary On
- Optimise iPad Storage On
- Upload to My Photo Stream On
- iCloud Photo Sharing On
- Summarise Photos On
- Keep Normal Photo On

In Mobile Data Settings

- Mobile Data On
- Mobile Data Options Roaming On
- Photos On but used only 33.4 kB so nothing not working

In iTunes and App Store settings (not necessarily relevant(

- Use Mobile Data On

iOS: 9.3.5
Hardware: iPad air

Answer (score 1):

Photos will not upload over a cellular connection. If you connect to a Wi-Fi network, go to Settings > Photos and verify that it says "Updated just now" or "Updated [some time recently]." If it does not say this, leave it on this page for a while and see whether it changes to some form of "Uploading."

Comment: It says updated at 0942, although time is now 0713. Not sure which day it is about.